# Какая комбинация клавиш открывает данную секцию?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hotkeys

[image: Было так]
[image: Стало так]

Какая комбинация клавиш открывает данную секцию ide???

Comment: View->Tool Window -> Project Alt+1

Answer (score 1):

> Alt + 1

P.s. неужели так сложно ввести несколько слов в гугл запрос "горячие клавиши intellij idea" вместо того что бы засорять ресурс

Comment: если бы я нашел, то не писал бы

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться комбинацией **Ctrl+E**, чтобы открыть вспомогательный диалог, а уже в нем выбрать **Project**.